# Why does AVG(x) give a different answer than AVR((isnull(x,0))?

Tags: sql, null, aggregate-functions

X is column with a mixture of numerical and null values.

I don't understand why treating null values as 0 changes the result of the AVG value.

Shouldn't it be like this,

```
(2 + null + 2) / 3 = 2 -- with null value

(2 + 0 + 2) / 3 = 2     -- no null value
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Forgot to indent 4 spaces haha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have `null` value, it is not being taken into account, hence number of elements (your `n`) is not increased, whereas `0` is treated as a valid value.

For example if you have: `1,1,6,7,null,3,2` it will be total `20` divided by **`6`** (i.e. `3.33`). However if you replace `null` with `0` it becomes `20` `/`**`7`** (i.e. `2.86`).

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2b3c/2) demonstrating this behavior on MySQL server.

**REFERENCE**: Have a look in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) right below the table:

```
This section describes group (aggregate) functions that operate on sets of values. Unless otherwise stated, group functions ignore NULL values.
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the clarification. Will mark your answer as correct as soon as I am able to =)

Comment: @iridescent: Glad to be of help :)